# can I do a patternProperties with $ref validation

Tags: jsonschema

I am trying to match a patternProperties with a schema, like, here is the jsonschema text:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"definitions": {
    "fabric_id": {
        "enum": [
            "ADMIN",
            "COPPER",
            "NETWORK",
            "STORAGE",
            "STORAGE2",
            "TENANT"
        ]
    },
    "fabrics": {
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "patternProperties": {
            "[A-Z0-9-]*": {
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "description": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "fabric_id": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/fabric_id",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "description",
                    "fabric_id"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            }
        },
        "type": "object"
    }
},
"description": "fabrics spec",
"properties": {
    "fabrics": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/fabrics"
    }
},
"required": [
    "fabrics"
],
"title": "network fabric",
"type": "object"
```

}

and here is my input json file:

```
{
"fabrics": {
    "ADMIN": {
        "description": "Primary bonded pair on the bigswitches.",
        "fabric_id": "ADMIN"
    },
    "COPPER": {
        "description": "Primary IPMI fabric on the tor switches.",
        "fabric_id": "COPPER"
    }
}
```

}

I can't figure out how to validate the patternProperty against the fabric_id enum?  The pattern object has fabric_id in it, and that is able to reference the fabric_id enum in the definitions section.  I'd like to have that same $ref for the "[A-z0-9-]*" pattern, but I just can't make it work.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This schema does is the best you can do. The only thing it can't do is constrain the property name to match the value of "fabric_id". Unfortunately, this is not possible with JSON Schema.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "fabrics": { "$ref": "#/definitions/fabrics" }
  },
  "required": ["fabrics"],
  "definitions": {
    "fabric_id": {
      "enum": ["ADMIN", "COPPER", "NETWORK"]
    },
    "fabrics": {
     "type": "object",
     "propertyNames": { "$ref": "#/definitions/fabric_id" },
     "patternProperties": {
        ".*": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "description": { "type": "string" },
            "fabric_id": { "$ref": "#/definitions/fabric_id" }
          },
          "required": ["description", "fabric_id"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I am starting to get this :-) I am using the python implementation of Julian/jsonschema. When I initially tried this I was surprised that it did, in fact, constrain the property name to match fabric_id!  Then, I had a power outage. When I got everything modified to try again it did not enforce that constraint. I found that I installed jsonschema via pip when the constraint failed. When I installed jsonschema from current master on github, the constraint was in effect.

Comment: If the property name and "fabric_id" are enforced to be the same, that's a bug! JSON Schema is not supposed to behave that way. I caution you not to rely on that behavior.

Comment: i am curious why you show propertyNames: { $ref: #/definitions/fabric_id } then? OH!  I see what you are saying.  They can be different values, but, they must both come from that fabric_id enum definition.  I get it!  In my schema I will eliminate the fabric_id attribute, and solely use the propertyNames.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't believe this is possible with draft-4 of JSON Schema.

If you can upgrade to 6 or 7 (+), you can make this possible.

`propertyNames`: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.8

> If the instance is an object, this keyword validates if every property name in the instance validates against the provided schema. Note the property name that the schema is testing will always be a string.

An example of how this can be used can be found at https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-org.github.io/issues/77

```
...    
"fooProperties": {
                "propertyNames": {
                    "$comment": "Need to anyOf these or else the enum and pattern conflict",
                    "anyOf": [
                        {"enum": ["foo1", "foo2"]},
                        {"pattern": "foo[A-Z][a-z0-9]*"}
                    ]
                }
            },
...
```

Sorry I don't have time to update your schema to follow this, but hopefully I sufficiently explained this for you to adapt it.

if you're unable to migrate beyond draft-4... well you'll have to do that validation aspect manually outside of JSON Schema.

Comment: the upgrading part was easy. i took a stab at changing my schema to use propertynames, haven't made it work yet, but it does look promising. thanks.

Comment: @Greg Feel free to join the JSON Schema Slack if you'd like further help and discussion =] (sorry, site is having issues today)

Comment: @Greg Did you manage to make it work or can I help you further?